# How do I prove $\mathbb{1}_{A_i} \rightarrow \mathbb{1}_{A}$ in a measure as $i \rightarrow \infty$ if and only if $\mu(A) <\infty$.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,M, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset ...$ be an increasing sequence of measurable sets such that $\mu(A_i)<\infty$ for every $I=1,2...$. Denote $A=\cup_{i=1} ^{\infty} A_i$

Prove that $\mathbb{1}_{A_i} \rightarrow \mathbb{1}_{A}$ in a measure as $i \rightarrow \infty$ if and only if $\mu(A) <\infty$.

Can anyone suggest some hints?

Comment: Write out the definition of $\Bbb 1_{A_i}\to \Bbb 1_A$ in measure: given $\epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(\{x\in X: |1_{A}(x) - \Bbb 1_{A_i}(x)|\geq \epsilon\})=0$. Using that $A_i\subset A$, can you rewrite the set in this limit?

Answer (score 2):

The main task is to show that "$1_{A_i} \to 1_A$ in measure" in this case is equivalent to "$\mu (A \setminus A_i) \to 0$ as $i \to \infty$." If you do that, then you can handle the two cases fairly straightforwardly.

- If $\mu(A) = \infty$, then $\mu(A \setminus A_i) = \mu(A) - \mu(A_i) = \infty$.
- If $\mu(A) < \infty$, then use the fact that $\mu(A_i) \to \mu(A)$ to show that $\mu(A \setminus A_i) = \mu(A) - \mu(A_i) \to 0$.